# NamedNativeQuery from two tables

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence

Is it possible to create class annotated with @Entity that in @NamedNativeQuery joins two different tables? For example native query is something like:

```
SELECT a.id as id, b.name as name
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b on a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id = :someValue and b.id = :someValue
```

What should I write in @Table annotation in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. The key is to use the @SqlResultSetMapping annotation. See [The javadoc for @SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html)

Comment: Thanks for help, however I have solved it by creating two different entities and @NamedQuery.